# setting up vhost in xampp

Tags: php, apache, vhosts

I am facing a minor problem while setting up vhost in xampp os - windows. here is the `httpd-vhosts.conf` in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/yiisite/basic/web/"
  ServerName yiisite
```

and in `hosts` file located `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

```
    127.0.0.1 yiisite
```

so when i hit i get `http://yiisite` i get what i want, but all other folders inside htdocs that i use to open in `localhost/abc` is all going to yiisite template 404 not found . cannot access other projects inside htdocs with localhost . if i change the port in vhosts.conf i can access localhost/abc but not yiisite

Comment: Do you have a virtualhost config and hosts entry for `localhost`?

Comment: i only config this for a particular file yiisite mentioned in vhosts DcoumentRoot and also have .htaccess for yiisite folder which i dont think is causing the issue. the port 80 is redirecting everything to yiisite

Comment: I dind't use Yii for a long time, but I simply think you configured the site using the localhost domain and all the routes are then using that host. The trouble should be in Yii config and not in your hosts file.

Comment: no i didnt changed anything in yii config except a random cookieValidation key and db name with opening urlmanager for pretty url in config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the `httpd-vhosts.conf` to

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
 DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/yiisite/basic/web/"
 ServerName yiisite
</VirtualHost>
```

solved the issue of conflicting with other projects inside htdocs and can access with `localhost/otherproject`